# Making a models form available in home index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

this is probably a very basic question.

I have installed rails 3 and generated a project, after that i generated a model called post and a home index which routed root to. To get the latest posts listed on the home index page i moved the necessary methods from the posts controller to the index controller and also the necessary code into the index.html.erb file of home.

I have tried moving all the create and edit methods from the post controller and also the _form.html.erb from the post views to try and print the post form on my index page using render 'form'.

But i get this error:

"undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class"

How can i solve this problem? Grateful for all help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the @post variable used by your form is not defined.
If you have moved your form in your index, verify that in the index action, you create both the @post and the @posts variable like this :

```
def index
  @post = Post.new
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

Comment: That worked, thanks alot man!! Now im gonna figure out why so i understand it. :)